# unable to find .bat pid for killing

Tags: windows, batch-file, pid, kill-process

I am unable to call a bat process within another bat.
This is the situation.

I have a n1.bat that basically contains:

```
TITLE "n1.bat"

...
...

start /b /MIN "n2.bat"
...
```

The n2.bat contains:

```
TITLE "n2.bat"

...
...

start someother.bat
start another.bat

exit
```

Now I use a third bat (n3.bat) that must kill everything.

```
TITLE "n3.bat"

...
TASKKILL /F /T /PID n1_PID
...

exit 0
```

Unfortunately when n3.bat ends a window called `n1.bat - n2.bat` remains active (the echo output belongs to n2.bat).
I tried to kill it in some ways:

1- Tried to get the process pid from tasklist **->** there is no process called n2.bat or similar

```
TASKLIST /V /NH>Tasks.txt
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims= " %%n2_pid IN ('FINDSTR n2.bat Tasks.txt') DO SET PID=%%n2_pid
TASKKILL /PID %n2_pid%
```

2- Trying to use `TASKKILL /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq n2.bat"` **->** no process found

I tried the previous solutions also starting n2.bat with
`start /min "n2.bat"` (so without `/b`)
with no success.

The only way I manage to kill it is to calling

```
TASKKILL /F /IM cmd.exe
```

that I really would like to avoid since it obviously kills all opened cmd.

Any ideas to retrieve the guilty pid?

Comment: You generally wouldn't `Start` a `.bat`/`.cmd` file, you'd `Call` one!

Comment: You can directly kill a process by its windows title :  `TASKKILL /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq n1*"`